# In which paper did this formula appear?

Tags: regression, correlation, references, regression-coefficients

I want to use this formula in my paper, but I don't know which paper or book to cite. Can anyone tell me which paper I should cite?Thank you!

The formula is related to linear regression.

$\hat{Y}_i = r\frac{S_y}{S_x}(X_i - \bar{X}) + \bar{Y}$

here ${Y}_i$ is predicted value, $r$ is correlation coefficient, $S$ is variance,$X$ is features of samples, $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ are mean value of features and target values,respectively.

Comment: I removed the `[machine-learning]` tag because it's unrelated. Same with `[multiple-linear-regression]` as you ask about simple linear regression.

Comment: It's a trivial identity. Do you recognize that this (almost) is the least squares regression model?

Comment: Something like this formula will be in any book that covers linear regression, although it may need a little bit of algebra to get it in this form. I  don't think you even need to cite a book.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is basic statistics, it should be covered in introductory handbooks. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) quotes one such book by Kenney and Keeping (1962), or just quote Wikipedia itself.